# Is it possible to convert Gregorian to Hijri date in Vb?

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I have a table in sql where the date format is stored in Hijri. Now I am working on a vb.net application where I have to let the user update that dateField.

So is it possible that if I place a datepicker(which is in Gregorian) and user selects the date and its converts into Hijri date before updating. I mean when the user selects the date and clicks the save button the date should be updated in hijri format in the sql .

For now , the user is entering the date manually on a tms AdvEdit.

Is there any code available to accomplish this task. Thanking you all in advance for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below code will convert to Gregorian/ Hijri according to the parameter passed:

```
   Public Function ConvertDateCalendar(ByVal DateConv As DateTime, 
ByVal Calendar As String, ByVal DateLangCulture As String) As String

        Dim DTFormat As DateTimeFormatInfo
        DateLangCulture = DateLangCulture.ToLower()
        ''' We can't have the hijri date writen in English. We will get a runtime error - LAITH - 11/13/2005 1:01:45 PM -

        If Calendar = "Hijri" AndAlso DateLangCulture.StartsWith("en-") Then
            DateLangCulture = "ar-sa"
        End If

       ''' Set the date time format to the given culture - LAITH - 11/13/2005 1:04:22 PM -
       DTFormat = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo(DateLangCulture, False).DateTimeFormat

       ''' Set the calendar property of the date time format to the given calendar - LAITH - 11/13/2005 1:04:52 PM -
       Select Case Calendar
           Case "Hijri"
               DTFormat.Calendar = New System.Globalization.HijriCalendar()
               Exit Select

           Case "Gregorian"
               DTFormat.Calendar = New System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar()
               Exit Select
           Case Else

               Return ""
       End Select

       ''' We format the date structure to whatever we want - LAITH - 11/13/2005 1:05:39 PM -
       DTFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy"
       Return (DateConv.[Date].ToString("f", DTFormat))
   End Function
```

Happy coding !!!!!

Comment: I am getting this error when I try the above: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified time is not supported in this calendar. It should be between 07/18/0622 00:00:00 (Gregorian date) and 12/31/9999 23:59:59 (Gregorian date), inclusive

Answer (score 1):

Dear Ahmad, .net Provides a PersianCalendar Class which do this for you.

All you need is to Create an instance from PersianCalendar and use it. All methods are familier Like

```
 System.Globalization.PersianCalendar pc = new PersianCalendar();
 pc.GetDayOfMonth(YourDate); // and so on
```

note that All .net Libraries are same and you can use them in each .Net platform language(likeVB, C#, etc) and all of them will compile to CLR, So Just Create an instance and Ride.

I Also Strongly recommand you to store Georgian date to your DB andwhen you want to display the date, Convert it to persian or any other calendar, this let you globalize you application simpler.

And Note that Microsoft Added Hijri Shamsi Calendar to .Net 4 as a type of calendar and you do not need to convert it any more in .net 4.0

GoodLuck